# Config Gitlab webhook with gitlabMergeCommitSha parameter

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I've a pipeline (groovy) that define some stage which using `gitlabCommitStatus`

The problem is when jenkin checkout using gitlab plugin with merge action (merge with squash commits option) it has issue but the pipeline no error if not use squash options during merge.

I'm going to apply the parameter `gitlabMergeCommitSha` which mention in this [PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/pull/1467), but I'm not sure what should be change in order to make pipeline working as that parameter behaviors

`Jenkins will check out git repository to squash/merge commit, not to the last commit from source branch.`

If someone has experience how to apply this parameter please share

[image]

Thank you for your time!.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrade the plugin, and observer few week. I think It's working, no need extra action requires